# Using classes to make pieces in chess. Having trouble setting up pawns

Tags: python-3.x, chess

The exact way I have the board setup is temporary but it's a list:

```
Board = []

for y in range(64):
    Board.append(x)
```

I then created a class to start setting up pieces:

```
class Piece:

    def __init__(self, type_colour, image, position):
        self.type_colour = type_colour
        self.image = image
        self.position = position
```

To replace, let's say, 0 to 7 with pawns, I've done this:

```
for x in range(8):
    Board[x] = Piece(pawnW, "♙", x)
```

I'll sort out pawnW and how to display "♙" later.

When doing it like this, will it create 8 separate objects that can be moved independently? Is there a better way to do it? I'll be calculating the available moves based on its initial position and I don't want to be accidentally moving all the pieces at once.

I'm quite the beginner and literally only learned about classes half an hour ago and after successfully doing a Tic-Tac-Tow game that my mate challenged me to do, he told to try and build a functional chessboard. Any advice would be extremely helpful. Cheers.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Yes, this will give you unique pieces. However, designing a chess game is a pretty complex topic and a bit on the broad side to be on topic here. Very likely, your `Piece` class will be subclassed with `Pawn`, `Bishop` etc classes, and you can get into even more granularity by subclassing with intermediate abstractions like `SlidingPiece`, `JumpingPiece` if you want. Can you try to narrow the problem down to something specific? Thanks and good luck with your game!

Comment: Yes, it will create 8 different objects. There might be better ways, but for your design this is also OK.